# Set dynamically created Java String to Json Values to perform Karate Integration Testing as a dynamically

Tags: json, spring-boot, karate

I need to set the randomString/randomNumber to a Json Values. Current to complete my Karate Integration testing, I am passing hardcoded values as payload, But need to set the randomString/randomNumber as value for Json. I am having PUT HTTP verb.

I need to store the JSON values in DB as well.

Comment: I also need to set generated Json Values in karate feature file. Please help me with your valuable inputs.

Comment: first - you need to improve the quality of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks!! I will improve the question quality.  Once again trying to explain my question. I need write feature file for Microservice Integration testing. The values passing in payload for each HTTP method are

Answer (score 1):

Do you need just generate random value(number or string) and write it to you JSON, i right understand?

Answer (score 0):

write some java code to generate random String/content and use in karate feature as below:

```
def emailID = common.getRandomString(7)+'@test.mail'

When def payload = <someData>

And set payload $.email = emailID
And request payload
```

Hope this solve your problem